# iPhone Linking to an iTunes page

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I found a page (http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker) to get the iTunes url for a specific page which I assume should direct the user out of my app and into the corresponding page in the app store.

I have never done this or any other UIWebView stuff but after some searching I found some code that I thought would work that uses UIApplication.h.

My code is:

```
#import <UIApplication.h>

//...in a tableView....
case 8:
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *) http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lockbox-pro/id288460603?mt=8&uo=4;
break;
```

openURL has an error saying that it is undeclared - but I imported the UIApplication.h file.  Then I saw that the UIApplication import also had an error on it.  I don't think that I want to use UIWebView because from what I understand, that opens up the URL in the app itself - I want to direct the user to the App Store.  Where am I going wrong?

EDIT:  Okay, I changed it to a simple button that is supposed to close the app and bring the user to the itunes page:

```
- (IBAction) pressedFull {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

}

I linked it in IB - it still crashes the app when the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has a number of things wrong in just one line. First, you're typing the method signature rather than using the method properly (ie, sending a message to an object). Second, you're not enclosing the string.

Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yoururlhere"]];
```

With respect, you should review the [Learning Objective-C: a Primer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594) thoroughly until you are more comfortable with the syntax as well. A quick look at some of your other questions suggests this is your biggest issue. You'll be doing yourself a huge favor by setting all else aside and concentrating on getting Objective-C well and truly under your belt before continuing.

Comment: It runs but:
1 - I am getting an error stating that the url passed is an NSString and it should be an NSURL.
2 - When I click on the link it crashes the program.
(I know that I need to do some more research into the basics but I am very close to finishing this app and want to complete it before go back to that.)

Comment: (facepalm) You're right. [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://yoururlhere"]];

Comment: It compiles but then crashes when you click on the URL.  I am getting a cautionary error (yellow sign) that says - 'NSURL' may not respond to '+urlWithString:'

Comment: Okay - figured it out - urlWithString doesn't work - but URLWithString works!

Comment: Yeah, kind of an off day today. Need to check my details before I post them. :-} Sorry for the confusion.